# Swift Casting on Pre iPhone 6 Devices

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, swift

For some reason this line of code is crashing on pre iPhone 6 devices:

```
var friendMatch = newDict.objectForKey("is_match") as Int
```

The dictionary is generated from JSON that I receive from an endpoint. The JSON looks like this:

```
"is_match" = 1;
```

I've also tried:

```
var friendMatch: NSNumber = newDict.objectForKey("is_match") as NSNumber
```

And the app still crashes on that line. The crash log is unhelpful.

[image]

Any thoughts on why this is working on iPhone 6 and 6+, but not on older devices?

Comment: "The crash log is unhelpful" No it isn't.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var friendMatch = newDict.objectForKey("is_match") as Int
```

You should not be casting unconditionally. Cast conditionally instead:

```
if let friendMatch = newDict.objectForKey("is_match") as? Int {
    // ...
}
```

Now if the cast fails you won't crash.

Comment: Hey matt I just realized this right before you posted it! I had figured that since the JSON key value was not an object, but rather an Int value, that it would always at least initialize to 0. But perhaps not?

Comment: Actually it's not an Int and it isn't initialized to anything. It's an Optional wrapping an AnyObject and that's all you know. So you're making a lot of assumptions here - that this thing is not nil, and that it can be unwrapped to get an AnyObject, and that this AnyObject can be cast to an Int. I don't know any of that, and clearly neither do you. The conditional expresses the necessary caution... :)

Answer (score 0):

Could you add some more code? It could be that you are not properly decoding the `NSData` JSON into a dictionary.

Also, use literal syntax, it is cleaner and easier to read.

```
newDict["is_match"]
```

If you are reading the JSON fine, then before casting it to anything, try adding a `println` to see the value inside it, or breakpoints.

```
println(newDict["is_match"])
```

**Post Discussion edit:**

Try:

```
var newInt = newDict["is_match"].toInt()
```

Comment: The values are printing as they should be. The data is all fine. It is simply just crashing on that line of code on the devices I mentioned. The JSON is just an integer value, not in string format or any other format.

Comment: perhaps crude, but I am resolved to help you here! Perhaps try, instead of casting with as, use toInt? see my edited answer.